# storing data in javascript array for further use

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have page Users where profiles are displayed with some basic data: profile photo, nickname, age, location etc. When you click on profile, it loads data with ajax and shows user profile in pop up. So you stay on the same page.

But every ajax call needs some time to call serverside code and get data. It is not slow, but I want to make user profile display ultra fast. I was thinking that it would be much faster if I pull all profile data at the first place when I get profiles list. Instead of getting just some data on the Users page, I can pull all profile data. Then I can save the data in javascript as array. When user will click on profile, it won't make ajax call but it will pull data from javascript array. In this way, I think pop up will be shown rapidly.

So far this is just idea. Is it ok to store data I received in javascript array or is any better method?

Comment: Have you considered using memcache ???

Comment: But even using memcache, ajax call will be required. I want to make look that when you click at profile it displays profile promptly, like desktop application.

Comment: @user1324762, but subsequent calls will be a lot faster

Comment: If the user data is not too big, you could use hidden html elements that are displayed on click. 
The page would be fully built on 1st load, and on click, you just pick the appropriate element and show that.

Comment: Maybe you could send to the user only the data that he wants, and store it in his computer using localStorage or something like those new HTML5 technologies (I'm not an expert). And the next time you don't have to send the data again, just use the stored data.

Comment: You don't have to use ajax, since the data is not changing all the time just use memcache and your session storage and save it in your session

Comment: @Pinetree I feel like that would have some security flaws?

Comment: @SimonMacIntyre Why, everything is accessible anyway, either like this, or by using ajax calls. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Pinetree I don't want to use hidden elements for seo purposes. For security you are right, no problem about that.

Comment: How many users? It may be a very big chunk of data.

Comment: @MattGibson 10 users per page, I think this is not a problem because I can clear data on each new page.

Comment: @Baba I forgot to mention that the data is not static and will be changing. For each new search can be other users.

Comment: I agree with @Pinetree Ajax Call can also be monitored  but you can create hidden HTML Tag with hidden data and some clever encryption ...  but if the database changes its also usless ..

Comment: i think you should be look at how to improve for ajax speed and maximize use of cache systems

Comment: If you use local storage, how will you know when the user profile has changed or the UP data needs to be refreshed for some reason? I would also recommend looking into improving the speed of your ajax requests - properly optimised ajax can be almost instantaneous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use javascript object

get the user info in php and pass them to a function in js in the html

```
<script>buildUserInfo(array('user_id,yaz,20,male,837367.jpg',....));</script>
```

then create a js object and but these value in

```
var userObject = new Object();
function buildUserInfo(data){
  for(var i=0;i<data.length();i++){
    var dataIn = data[i].split(',');
    userObject[user_id].name = dataIn[0]; 
    userObject[user_id].age = dataIn[1]; 
    userObject[user_id].gender = dataIn[2]; 
    userObject[user_id].photo = dataIn[3]; 
}}
```

and then you can access them by simply call the object
if you whant the name just call  `userObject[user_id].name`

update:
for multiple users by creating an object array i edit the code above

Comment: That is what I was thinking. I wasn't sure if simple array is a good idea.

Comment: @mplungjan he can pass it as he want i pass it as an array
he can pass as json and then decode it in the function

Comment: @user1324762 its the fastest way or just go with  mplungjan and use json instead of array
im here giving you directions not the exact solution

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html):

> *So what is HTML5 Storage? Simply put, it’s a way for web pages to store named key/value pairs locally, within the client web browser. Like cookies, this data persists even after you navigate away from the web site, close your browser tab, exit your browser, or what have you. Unlike cookies, this data is never transmitted to the remote web server (unless you go out of your way to send it manually).*

Although it is a newer feature that not all older browsers support, you can use a library like [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) to mitigate these cases.

> *jStorage makes use of HTML5 local storage where available and userData behavior in Internet Explorer older versions.*

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use JSON? Initialize the json object on page load like this and you will have all data instantly without any ajax requests.

```
var users = <?php echo json_encode($users); ?>;
```